# openDrawer() from a screen of a child navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following react-native code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {View,Text,Button} from 'react-native';

class Sub extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: () => (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().openDrawer()}
        title="Open Drawer"
      />
    ),
  };
  render() {
      const props = this.props;
      return (
        <View>
        <Text>{props.navigation.state.routeName}</Text>
        <Button onPress={_=>props.navigation.navigate("Sub1")} title="Sub1" />
        <Button onPress={_=>props.navigation.navigate("Sub2")} title="Sub2" />
        </View>
      );
  }
}

const SubRoutes = {
    "Sub1":Sub
};

const SubNavigator = createStackNavigator(SubRoutes);

const SubApp = createAppContainer(SubNavigator);

const MainRoutes = {
    "Main1":SubApp
};

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(MainRoutes);

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

AppRegistry.registerComponent("nav", () => App);
```

It presents a StackNavigator as a child of a DrawerNavigator.  In the `Sub` screen, I have a `headerTitle` with a button, when clicked, I want to open the drawer menu of the drawer navigator. Right now clicking on the button just gives the error that `Sub.props.navigation` doesn't exist.

How do I cause the drawer menu to open when the header title button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your `navigationOptions` code to this:

```
  ...
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerTitle: () => (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
        title="Open Drawer"
      />
    )
  });
  ...
```